# Do I need a pre-paid hotel reservation to apply for a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, indian-citizens

I would like to know if pre-paid hotel accommodation is mandatory to apply for a Schengen visa? Since I have fully paid flight tickets, should I also go for pre-paid hotel accommodation?

Right now I have only reserved a hotel room on [Booking.com](http://www.booking.com/) which can be cancelled free of charge. I am an Indian citizen applying at the German embassy.

Comment: What's your country of citizenship and where would you apply for the visa?

Comment: from India, At German embassy

Comment: You have the option of a reservation you can later cancel for free, where's the issue ? You have nothing to lose.

Answer (score 4):

A hotel reservation, or other proof of accommodation is required as part of the Schengen visa process.

The only actual requirement is that the reservation have the following:

1. Your name (ideally, it should be the same as the name on your passport).
2. Arrival and departure dates.
3. Address of the venue/hotel.

Sometimes if you are part of a group, the travel reservation doesn't have all the names of all the passengers and this causes issues at the embassy.

Beyond this - does it have to be confirmed (paid) reservation - it is not specifically mentioned in the requirements.

For example, [this pdf for requirements](http://kuwait.nlembassy.org/binaries/content/assets/postenweb/k/koeweit/netherlands-embassy-in-kuwait/import/visa_for_the_netherlands/all_other_visas/visa-requirements-schengen.pdf) for Schengen from the embassy of the Netherlands lists the following (for tourist visas):

1. Application and a photo that is no more than 6 months old.
2. Passport has to be valid for 3 months after the validity of the visa.
3. Copy of passport (id page)
4. Copy of your national id (if applicable)
5. Previous passport (if had a Schengen visa)
6. Copy of flight reservation and hotel booking for the entire period of stay in the Schengen Area
7. Copy of travel insurance, with minimum coverage of 30,000 EUR
8. Visa fee of 60 EUR in local currency
9. Employment letter
10. Valid residence permit endorsed in document (for foreigners)
11. Bank statement for the past 6 months